# Not able to parse Latitude & longitude to ogr_geometry

Tags: geometry, sql-server

I have a table (Table1) of locations with Latitude and Longitude values.

```
Loc_Nm || geocode_latitude || geocode_longitude
   A   ||    43.43044      ||    -80.0910793
   W   ||    43.9114523    ||    -80.0911329
   X   ||    43.9209011    ||    -80.091323
   Y   ||    43.9083203    ||    -80.0913039
   Z   ||    43.914577     ||    -80.091198
```

I downloaded shapefiles for "Federal Electoral Districts - Canada 2015 (English)" from the link given below.

https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/737be5ea-27cf-48a3-91d6-e835f11834b0

The, Shaepfile was in "3347 - NAD83_Statistics_Canada_Lambert" projection and as I dealing with Logitudes and Latitudes, I converted it to "4326 - GCS_WGS_1984" projection. I achieved this through ogr2ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -t_srs EPSG:4326 -s_srs EPSG:3347 FED_CA_2_2_ENG_Modified.shp FED_CA_2_2_ENG.shp
```

Then, I loaded the resulting Shapefile to Local SQL Server DB using the ogrogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=RBANSAL\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySpatial;trusted_connection=yes" C:\Users\rbansal\Desktop\ShapeFile\FED_CA_2_2_ENG_Modified.shp -nln "Spatial_Data" -progress
```

[image: Table2]
Now, I need to group the Table1 locations as per the Federal Ridings loaded into the "Spatial_Data" Table above. I am using below given query for that purpose. It runs for quite a while but, eventually completes with 0 records.

```
select * from MySpatial.dbo.Spatial_Data s, MySpatial.dbo.geocodes_raw g 
where ogr_geometry.STContains(geometry::Parse('POINT(' + CAST(g.geocode_longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(g.geocode_latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'))=1;
```

It runs for quite a while but, eventually completes with 0 records.

What is possibly wrong here?

Comment: try using latitude, longitude

Comment: @IanTurton, Just tried that. The query ran for like 36 minutes and still no results.

Comment: Try displaying the Shapefile (2) in a GIS to validate it is located where expected

Comment: @JGH, the Converted Shapefile (from ESPG: 3347 to 4326), shows the areas in the correct coordinates. Plus, I also checked the 'Spatial Results' in the SQL Server, and the results show correctly there within the expected longitudes and latitudes.

Answer (score 1):

`STContains` [returns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stcontains-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) `null` if the SRIDs of the two geometries don't match.

When you create the point, the `geometry::parse` method [assumes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/parse-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) an SRID of 0, which makes every comparison fail.

You could try build the points specifying the SRID using the [`point`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/point-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) function

```
select * 
from MySpatial.dbo.Spatial_Data s, 
     MySpatial.dbo.geocodes_raw g 
where ogr_geometry.STContains(
           geometry::Point(g.geocode_longitude, 
                           g.geocode_latitude,
                           4326))=1;
```

Comment: I tried but even after about 24 Hours, this query is still executing.

Comment: @RAVIBANSAL The time it takes sounds like an indexing issue

Comment: I am not so sure, @JGH. In the past, I have used the same `MySpatial.dbo.geocodes_raw` table for grouping locations against Provincial Locations derived from Provincial Ridings Shapefiles and it worked fine (took about 6-7 hours) with the same query as I posted in my question. The only difference between when it worked fine and now is the Shapefile and the derived geometry information. Can you please check the information I have given in my question and see if I am doing it right or if I have missed something or if there is something wrong with this particular Shapefile?

Comment: can you please help me here?

Comment: @RAVIBANSAL using to the provided information, I don't see what else could be the issue. You could try cutting a bit of the far north so it doesn't go to lat 89.9999